# Get a Windows Forms control by name in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, string, controls, accessibility

I have a `ToolStripMenuItem` called `myMenu`. How can I access this like so:

```
/* Normally, I would do: */
this.myMenu... etc.

/* But how do I access it like this: */
String name = myMenu;
this.name...
```

This is because I am dynamically generating ToolStripMenuItems from an XML file and need to reference MenuItems by their dynamically generated names.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Use the [Control.ControlCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx) method.

Try this:

```
this.Controls.Find()
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I think because, as o3o has pointed out, a ToolStripMenuItem is not a Control.

Comment: For a textbox, I had to cast to the control type and take the first element like this: `((TextBox) frm.Controls.Find("controlName",true)[0]).Text = "yay";`

Comment: @DanW this is so much like Java

Comment: What if I have a part of the name and I need a list of controls who have that string in their name?

Comment: Thanks @mrid! This is what worked for me when I'm using one function for all textboxes in powershell. I hope this helps anyone else. 

([TextBox]$MainForm.Controls.Find($this.Name,$true)[0]).SelectAll()

Answer (score 52):

```
string name = "the_name_you_know";

Control ctn = this.Controls[name];

ctn.Text = "Example...";
```

Comment: the only issue with ToolStripMenuItem is that it is not a Control and your code won't work. ;(

Comment: Actually this answer is closer to the question to me.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you have the `menuStrip` object and the menu is only one level deep, use:

```
ToolStripMenuItem item = menuStrip.Items
    .OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>()
    .SelectMany(it => it.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>())
    .SingleOrDefault(n => n.Name == "MyMenu");
```

For deeper menu levels add more SelectMany operators in the statement.

if you want to search all menu items in the strip then use

```
ToolStripMenuItem item = menuStrip.Items
    .Find("MyMenu",true)
    .OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>()
    .Single();
```

However, make sure each menu has a different name to avoid exception thrown by key duplicates.

To avoid exceptions you could use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault` / `Single`, or just return a sequence if you might have `Name` duplicates.

Comment: This should be the right solution. Other people did not know that ToolStripMenuItem is not control. Due to this reason their solutions do not work for ToolStripMenuItem.

Answer (score 8):

```
Control GetControlByName(string Name)
{
    foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
        if(c.Name == Name)
            return c;

    return null;
}
```

Disregard this, I reinvent wheels.

Comment: More of a general-purpose-ish solution than Julien's. Still works fine though.

Comment: this is not reinventing the wheel, it's a good solution that can be easily adapted to the case where you don't know a control's name or want to view the names of each control or do many things accessing controls, and was thus useful to me.

Answer (score 5):

Using the same approach of [Philip Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190145/philip-wallace), we can do like this:

```
    public Control GetControlByName(Control ParentCntl, string NameToSearch)
    {
        if (ParentCntl.Name == NameToSearch)
            return ParentCntl;

        foreach (Control ChildCntl in ParentCntl.Controls)
        {
            Control ResultCntl = GetControlByName(ChildCntl, NameToSearch);
            if (ResultCntl != null)
                return ResultCntl;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Example:

```
    public void doSomething() 
    {
            TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox) this.GetControlByName(this, "mytextboxname");
            myTextBox.Text = "Hello!";
    }
```

I hope it help! :)

Answer (score 5):

One of the best way is a single row of code like this:

In this example we search all `PictureBox` by name in a form

```
PictureBox[] picSample = 
                    (PictureBox)this.Controls.Find(PIC_SAMPLE_NAME, true);
```

Most important is the second paramenter of `find`.

if you are certain that the control name exists you can directly use it:

```
  PictureBox picSample = 
                        (PictureBox)this.Controls.Find(PIC_SAMPLE_NAME, true)[0];
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use find function in your Form class. If you want to cast (Label) ,(TextView) ... etc, in this way you can use special features of objects. It will be return Label object.

```
(Label)this.Controls.Find(name,true)[0];
```

**name**: item name of searched item in the form

**true**: Search all Children boolean value

Answer (score 4):

*this.Controls.Find(name,  searchAllChildren)* doesn't find ToolStripItem because *ToolStripItem* is not a Control

```
  using SWF = System.Windows.Forms;
  using NUF = NUnit.Framework;
  namespace workshop.findControlTest {
     [NUF.TestFixture]
     public class FormTest {
        [NUF.Test]public void Find_menu() {
           // == prepare ==
           var fileTool = new SWF.ToolStripMenuItem();
           fileTool.Name = "fileTool";
           fileTool.Text = "File";

           var menuStrip = new SWF.MenuStrip();
           menuStrip.Items.Add(fileTool);

           var form = new SWF.Form();
           form.Controls.Add(menuStrip);

           // == execute ==
           var ctrl = form.Controls.Find("fileTool", true);

           // == not found! ==
           NUF.Assert.That(ctrl.Length, NUF.Is.EqualTo(0)); 
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
this.Controls["name"];
```

This is the actual code that is ran:

```
public virtual Control this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            int index = this.IndexOfKey(key);
            if (this.IsValidIndex(index))
            {
                return this[index];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

vs:

```
public Control[] Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("key", SR.GetString("FindKeyMayNotBeEmptyOrNull"));
    }
    ArrayList list = this.FindInternal(key, searchAllChildren, this, new ArrayList());
    Control[] array = new Control[list.Count];
    list.CopyTo(array, 0);
    return array;
}

private ArrayList FindInternal(string key, bool searchAllChildren, Control.ControlCollection controlsToLookIn, ArrayList foundControls)
{
    if ((controlsToLookIn == null) || (foundControls == null))
    {
        return null;
    }
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < controlsToLookIn.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((controlsToLookIn[i] != null) && WindowsFormsUtils.SafeCompareStrings(controlsToLookIn[i].Name, key, true))
            {
                foundControls.Add(controlsToLookIn[i]);
            }
        }
        if (!searchAllChildren)
        {
            return foundControls;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < controlsToLookIn.Count; j++)
        {
            if (((controlsToLookIn[j] != null) && (controlsToLookIn[j].Controls != null)) && (controlsToLookIn[j].Controls.Count > 0))
            {
                foundControls = this.FindInternal(key, searchAllChildren, controlsToLookIn[j].Controls, foundControls);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        if (ClientUtils.IsSecurityOrCriticalException(exception))
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return foundControls;
}
```

Comment: what is `ClientUtils.IsSecurityOrCriticalException` ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `Windows.Form Form1` as the parent form which owns the menu you've created. One of the form's attributes is named `.Menu`. If the menu was created programmatically, it should be the same, and it would be recognized as a menu and placed in the Menu attribute of the Form.

In this case, I had a main menu called `File`. A sub menu, called a `MenuItem` under `File` contained the tag `Open` and was named `menu_File_Open`. The following worked. Assuming you

```
// So you don't have to fully reference the objects.
using System.Windows.Forms;

// More stuff before the real code line, but irrelevant to this discussion.

MenuItem my_menuItem = (MenuItem)Form1.Menu.MenuItems["menu_File_Open"];

// Now you can do what you like with my_menuItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're generating them dynamically, keep a map between a string and the menu item, that will allow fast retrieval.

```
// in class scope
private readonly Dictionary<string, ToolStripMenuItem> _menuItemsByName = new Dictionary<string, ToolStripMenuItem>();

// in your method creating items
ToolStripMenuItem createdItem = ...
_menuItemsByName.Add("<name here>", createdItem);

// to access it
ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = _menuItemsByName["<name here>"];
```

Comment: Now THERE'S an idea! +1 (although only works if the control is already in the dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ToolStrip.Items collection. It even has a find method available.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
private ToolStripMenuItem getToolStripMenuItemByName(string nameParam)
   {
      foreach (Control ctn in this.Controls)
         {
            if (ctn is ToolStripMenuItem)
               {
                   if (ctn.Name = nameParam)
                      {
                         return ctn;
                      }
                }
         }
         return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to iterate through the `Controls` list in a `foreach` loop. Something like this:

```
foreach (Control child in Controls)
{
    // Code that executes for each control.
}
```

So now you have your iterator, `child`, which is of type `Control`. Now do what you will with that, personally I found this in a project I did a while ago in which it added an event for this control, like this:

```
child.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(dragDown);
```