# Can't find this.Controls - what am I missing?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Sorry for a potentially dumb question, I am still new at this.  I really appreciate your help.
Referring to [Get a Windows Forms control by name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/c-get-control-by-name/1536756#1536756)
But I don't have a "this.Controls" available.  Is there something I am missing here?

In other words, when I type "this." and visual studio populates a list of option, there is no "Controls" option.

Comment: What is "this" in your code context?

Comment: The question you linked to is for Winforms, and you're using WPF.

Comment: Some context would be helpful.  What is "this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to iterate through the controls for whatever reason, in your Window class, you can iterate through the LayoutRoot's children (e.g.)

```
    foreach (object o in this.LayoutRoot.Children)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(o.GetType().Name);
    }
```

Keep in mind that the children can also contain children, so you'll need to delve into each of those as needed.

Answer (score 4):

In WPF, you should try `this.FindName(string name)`

```
Button b = (Button)this.FindName("button1");
```

Answer (score 1):

The link you gave was for Winforms, you are looking for a WPF way to do it which is different.

Answer (score 0):

I have to add whats LayoutRoot:  because I am new in WPF I did not know whats that

After general research I found them: it's your Grid
if you write grid visual studio did not find them what you should do?

go to your window
next go to the Grid Start tag : `<grid>`
next add : `x:Name="your desired name"`

like this : `<Grid x:Name="FRM">`

now go back to code `yourwindow.xaml.cs`

not you see it works `foreach (object o in this.FRM.Children)`

I hope it was useful for a novice like me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very important issue when we want to make a change in similar controls in a particular Grid. So after looking up for a while I found out one solution which looks better.

I am performing a Null or Empty check on all the textboxes in my Grid when someone randomly presses the SUBMIT Button

Here is the C# Codeblock

```
foreach (TextBox tx in Grid1.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tx.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No empty boxes please!");
                return;
            }
        }
```