# Loop through Textboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have a winforms app that has 37 textboxes on the screen. Each one is sequentially numbered:

```
DateTextBox0
DateTextBox1 ...
DateTextBox37
```

I am trying to iterate through the text boxes and assign a value to each one:

```
int month = MonthYearPicker.Value.Month;
int year = MonthYearPicker.Value.Year;
int numberOfDays = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

m_MonthStartDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
m_MonthEndDate = new DateTime(year, month, numberOfDays);

DayOfWeek monthStartDayOfWeek = m_MonthStartDate.DayOfWeek;
int daysOffset = Math.Abs(DayOfWeek.Sunday - monthStartDayOfWeek);

for (int i = 0; i <= (numberOfDays - 1); i++)
{
 //Here is where I want to loop through the textboxes and assign values based on the 'i' value
   DateTextBox(daysOffset + i) = m_MonthStartDate.AddDays(i).Day.ToString();
}
```

Let me clarify that these textboxes appear on separate panels (37 of them). So in order for me to loop through using a foreach, I have to loop through the primary controls (the panels), then loop through the controls on the panels.  It starts getting complicated.

Any suggestions on how I can assign this value to the textbox?

Comment: Do you want to assign `TextBox.Name` or `TextBox.Text`?

Comment: I want to assign Textbox.Text to the textbox with the name = DateTextBox(daysoffset + i).

Comment: I have made an [API Proposal: Add Descendants property for Control](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/5195) on github.com/dotnet/winforms for this. If you like it, please upvote it there.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To get all controls and sub-controls recursively of specified type, use this extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TControl> GetChildControls<TControl>(this Control control) where TControl : Control
{
    var children = (control.Controls != null) ? control.Controls.OfType<TControl>() : Enumerable.Empty<TControl>();
    return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls<TControl>(c)).Concat(children);
}
```

usage:

```
var allTextBoxes = this.GetChildControls<TextBox>();
foreach (TextBox tb in allTextBoxes)
{
    tb.Text = ...;
}
```

Comment: +1 - that is almost exactly the code that I was about to post.

Comment: Don't you mean "foreach (TextBox tb in allTextBoxes)" for the loopiness?

Comment: Seems like the most elegant solution, but i get the error: "TControl ---> The type or namespace name 'TControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
". I searched MSDN, but didnt find that class. What to do?

Comment: @kiltek: this is the generic parameter declared as `where TControl : System.Web.Ui.Control` iirc.

Comment: I'm getting the error "Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations" (.net 4.0)

Comment: @TEK: Right! Don't know how I missed it and nobody noticed for so long time. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @abatishchev Wow. That has to be the fastest edit of all time. Thank you! (Ignore my previous comment, I am dumb).

Comment: @TEK: Yea, me is getting this error, too. And I'm applied the fix, please check it out. I'm just was digging into my very old code to figure out how this code being copy-pasted was working before. Hm. weird. Anyway, now should work. Let me know if it doesn't, please.

Comment: @abatishchev In it's current state, it works great! Thank you kindly for the extremely rapid response to a 4+ year old post. This has saved me having to do it the old dumb way.

Comment: Oddly enough, this works dandy except for a combobox that is populated with string values; in that case, the loop to set its SelectedIndex to -1 doesn't work. I have to set it explicitly after the loop for it to work. Why this would be, I don't know, but here is my code:
var allComboBoxes = this.GetChildControls<ComboBox>();
            foreach (ComboBox cmbx in allComboBoxes)
            {
                cmbx.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
            comboBoxDaysOfMonth.SelectedIndex = -1;

Comment: On third thought, this is happening to all the controls that are not directly on the form (those on a Panel or a Groupbox); I think that's probably the real issue/the crux of the biscuit.

Comment: I don't get how this gets ALL textboxes. For me, it only gets textboxes that are direct children of the form/given control. You still need to loop through each control with this solution, right?

Comment: @n00dles: the method calls itself recursively on all children of given type. Another option would be rewrite in and remove `OfType<T>`. So just return all children aka flatten the hierarchy. Then call `OfType<T>` to filter by given type.

Comment: I noticed the recursive call. I must have done something wrong then, coz it didn't return child controls. I found another similar method (but not an extension) that worked though. I don't yet understand lambda expressions, so it's hard for me to think it through.

Comment: @n00dles: post an answer if you found a better (or at least a similar) solution!

Answer (score 7):

You Could loop all the controls in the form asking one by one if it is a "Textbox" y ther return the complete List of them.

```
public List GetTextBoxes(){   
    var textBoxes = new List();   
        foreach (Control c in Controls){   
            if(c is TextBox){   
                textBoxes.add(c);   
        }   
    }   
return textBoxes;   
}
```

Comment: what if there might be additional text box which name happens to be fingering other than datatexrboc? will that count all text hides including one we don't need to count?

Answer (score 5):

Since this post seems to resurrect itself from time to time and since the solutions above do not find controls inside of controls, such as in a groupbox, this will find them. Just add your control type:

```
public static IList<T> GetAllControls<T>(Control control) where T : Control
{
    var lst = new List<T>();
    foreach (Control item in control.Controls)
    {
        var ctr = item as T;
        if (ctr != null)
            lst.Add(ctr);
        else
            lst.AddRange(GetAllControls<T>(item));
    }
    return lst;
}
```

And its use:

```
var listBoxes = GetAllControls<ListBox>(this);
foreach (ListBox lst in listBoxes)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: This worked for me (the top answer didn't). I put my method in a static class and had to set the method signature to " ... GetAllControls<T>(this Control control) ..." for it to work. The "this" would allow an instance of a control to call this extension method.

Answer (score 4):

You can loop through the textboxes in your form in a fairly simple manner:

```
Func<ControlCollection, List<TextBox>> SearchTextBoxes = null;
SearchTextBoxes = coll => {
    List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

    foreach (Control c in coll) {
        TextBox box = c as TextBox;
        if (box != null)
           textBoxes.Add(box);
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
           textBoxes.AddRange(SearchTextBoxes(c.Controls));
    }

    return textBoxes;
};

var tbs = SearchTextBoxes(this.Controls).OrderBy(tb => tb.Name);
```

Edit: Changed according to new requirements. Not nearly as elegant as the LINQ-solution, of course :)

Comment: That will miss any controls that are not located directly on the form (such as in a panel, tab page or similar).

Comment: I know I can loop through the controls but this screen contains 37 panels with the DateTextBoxes as well as another control.  So in order for me to get the data I have to loop through the panel controls and then the controls in the panel to get an array.  Is there a way for me to do this without using an array?  Just assign the DateTextBoxes the data it needs?

Comment: @bluefeet: See my answer to find how to loop through nested controls

Comment: Well, having them in panels changes things "a bit". You need to go recursive about it. Or even better, use the answer that abatishchev provided. It's pretty neat :)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through controls within form and check name of the control if matched then set Text property as you require.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (Control contrl in this.Controls) {
    if (contrl.Name == ("DateTextBox" + i.ToString())) {
        contrl.Text = "requiredtexttobeset";
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this mate...

```
foreach (TextBox txt in this.Panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                txt.Text="some value you assign";
            }
```

If your text boxes are on the form directly and not on a Panel then you can replace `this.Panel.Controls` with `this.Controls`. That should be short and clear enough for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do without 'foreach' (If you have specific boxes to adjust/address)

```
int numControls = Page.Form.Controls.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < numControls; i++)
    {
        if (Page.Form.Controls[i] is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox currBox = Page.Form.Controls[i] as TextBox;
            currbox.Text = currbox.TabIndex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        //THE EASY WAY! Always post easy solutions. It's the best way.
        //This code is used to loop through all textboxes on a form for data validation. 
        //If an empty textbox is found, Set the error provider for the appropriate textbox.
        foreach (var control in Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                //Box the control into a textbox. Not really needed, but do it anyway
                var textbox = (TextBox)control;

                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text))
                {
                    //Set the errorProvider for data validation
                    errorProvider1.SetError(textbox, "Data Required!");
                    textbox.Text = String.Empty; //Clear out the whitespace if necessary
                    //blnError = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `InitialiseComponents()` call, add the textboxes to a collection member variable on the form. You can then iterate through them in order later on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the name of control, therefore you can search the control by its name.

See [Get a Windows Forms control by name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/c-get-control-by-name)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Dictionary` of `TextBox`, `int` like the following

```
Dictionary<TextBox, int> textBoxes = new Dictionary<TextBox, int>();

foreach (TextBox control in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    textBoxes[control] = Convert.ToInt32(control.Name.Substring(11));
```

Now.. to loop through them..

```
foreach (var item in textBoxes.Select(p => new { textBox = p.Key, no = p.Value}))
     item.textBox.Text = item.no.ToString(); // whatever you want...
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Other answers just not cutting it for you?
I found this as an answer to a similar question on SO, but I can't find the thread now. It recursively loops through ALL controls of a given `type` which are located within a `control`. So includes children of children of children of... etc. My example changes the `ForeColor` of each `TextBox` to Hot Pink!

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControlsOfType(Control control, Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllControlsOfType(ctrl, type))
                              .Concat(controls)
                              .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```

Implementation:

```
IEnumerable<Control> allTxtBxs = GetAllControlsOfType(this, typeof(TextBox));
foreach (TextBox txtBx in allTxtBxs)
{
    txtBx.ForeColor = Color.HotPink;
}
```

Quite similar to [abatishchev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863138/4256973)(which, *for me*,  only returned *first-level* child controls), but different enough to merit it's own answer I think.