# How to Clear the TextBox Controls in a Panel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, textbox, updatepanel

I want to empty textbox controls in a Panel.
Please explain.

below is my code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_CreateLead" runat="server" Visible="false" BackColor="#eff2f6"  Width="98%">

<asp:Literal ID="LiteralNoLead" runat="server" Text="<span style='color:red'>No Lead Exists. Please fill the Lead Template to Create New Lead.</span>"></asp:Literal> 
<asp:Table ID="Table_CreateLead" runat="server" Width="98%"  CellSpacing="1"  CellPadding="1"  
        Font-Names="Tahoma" BorderColor="#eff2f6" BorderStyle="Dashed">
<asp:TableHeaderRow HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <asp:TableHeaderCell Text="Lead Template" Font-Bold="true" ColumnSpan="4"  Font-Size="Large" />
</asp:TableHeaderRow>
<asp:TableRow ID="TableRow11" runat="server">
       <asp:TableCell Text="General"  Font-Bold="true"  ForeColor="Blue"></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1"  runat="server">
    <asp:TableCell Text="Topic">
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal_Topic"  Text="<span style='color:red'>*</span>" runat="server" />
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="3">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_leadname" Width="80%" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_TextBox_leadname" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="TextBox_leadname" ValidationGroup="LeadVaidation" ErrorMessage="Enter Topic" />
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow> 
<asp:TableRow ID="TableRow23" runat="server">
   <asp:TableCell Text="Currency" ></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_Currency" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Text="No. of Employees" ></asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Employees" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    </asp:TableCell>
 </asp:TableRow>
 <asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Button ID="Button_lead" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="create_lead" ValidationGroup="LeadVaidation"/>
    </asp:TableCell>
     <asp:TableCell>
     <asp:Literal ID="Literal_lead" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
 </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
</asp:Panel>
```

I have used a method  clearText(Panel_CreateLead); on page load which does not work.

the code used in cleartext():

```
private void clearText(Panel PanelID)
{
     foreach (Control c in PanelID.Controls)
     {
         if (c is TextBox)
         {
             TextBox questionTextBox = c as TextBox; 
             if (questionTextBox != null)
             {
                 questionTextBox.Text = "";
             }
         }
     }
}
```

All these are not working. Please help.

Comment: Try the PreRender events instead of Page_Load....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863051/loop-through-textboxes

Answer (score 1):

This will only clear the text boxes that are direct children of you pannell.  In you code if you did something like the flowing it would work

```
private void clearText(control PanelID)
{
    foreach (Control c in PanelID.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox questionTextBox = c as TextBox; 
            if (questionTextBox != null)
            {
                questionTextBox.Text = "";
            }
        }

        if(c.Controls.count > 0)
        {
            cleartest(c)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive method to get all controls, or else you are going to get only the controls immediately under the panel. To [get all controls with a recursive method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253937/recursive-control-search-with-linq/253962#253962) you can use this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TextBox> GetAllControls(this Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        yield return control;
        foreach(Control descendant in control.GetAllControls())
        {
            yield return descendant;
        }
    }
}
```

You can modify to find only textbox, or you can use this method as `Panel.GetAllControls.OfType<TextBox>()` and work with all textboxes inside the panel.

Answer (score 1):

Extension method to get all controls by type recursively:

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetChildControls(this Control control) where TControl : Control
{
    var children = (control.Controls != null) ? control.Controls.OfType<Control>() : Enumerable.Empty<Control>();
    return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls(c)).Concat(children);
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = panel.Controls.GetChildControls().OfType<TextBox>();
foreach (TextBox tb in textBoxes)
{
    tb.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: @BrunoLM uses `yield`, I use `SelectMany()`

Comment: This is not recursive. Nest 4 panels and look for `TextBox` inside the last nested panel, starting from the top panel. It can't find the elements because it will only look elements inside `TextBox` but those are inside `Panel` http://pastebin.com/8wJQEgmA

Answer (score -1):

How to Empty the all textbox inside table, then `tr`, `td`, ...

```
foreach (Control c in Table3.Controls)
{
    if (c is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)
    {
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow tr;
        tr = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)c;
        foreach (Control td in tr.Controls)
        {
            if (td is System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell)                        
            {
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell td1;
                td1 = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell)td;
                    foreach (Control txtBox in td1.Controls)
                    {
                        if(txtBox is TextBox)
                        {
                            TextBox tt = txtBox as TextBox;
                            tt.Text = string.Empty;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```