# Changing the BackColor of a textbox upon entry

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following code for my form:

```
    private void txt1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt1.SelectAll();
        txt1.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
    }

    private void txt2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt2.SelectAll();
        txt2.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;            
    }

    private void txt1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtThermalConductivity.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

    private void txt2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtThermalConductivity.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
```

There are another 20 textboxes on my form that I would like to do the same for. Is it possible to combine all of the enter events and all of the leave events so I have two events in total rather than 44 individual events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Designer view, select each textbox and set the `Enter` and `Leave` events to point to a single implementation of each.

Then you can do this:

```
private void txt_enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ((TextBox)sender).BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
}

private void txt_leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ((TextBox)sender).BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Also, `SelectAll` isn't required because you're setting the entire textbox's background color.. not the `SelectionColor` of a `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Brilliant thanks! The 'SelectAll' is there to select all text on entering each textbox, making it quicker to change the input.

Answer (score 1):

You could either add manually or iterate over all textboxes in form (extension method found here [GetChildControls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863051/loop-through-textboxes).

```
foreach (TextBox textBox in this.GetChildControls<TextBox>())
{
    textBox.Enter += new EventHandler(TextBox_Enter);
    textBox.Leave += new EventHandler(TextBox_Leave);
}
```

The above can be called from the Form's Load event.

The event listener now can look like the following  by casting the sender to TextBox.

```
 private void TextBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)sender;
    txtBox .SelectAll();
    txtBox .BackColor = Color.LightBlue;            
}

private void TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)sender;
    txtBox.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is, just use something like the following:

```
private void tbLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
((TextBox) sender).BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

The set the controls event declaration to point to this function.

You can also do the same for the Leave() event.

(Just a little note to say, I much prefer to handle this kind of thing client side where possible.)

Comment: The OP doesn't state this is a web form.