# count the number of textboxes used and use that value to end loop

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and i would like to know how to count the total number of textBox to end the loop. So, for example: if there are 8 textBoxes and the user entered values in 5 out of 8, i would like to know how to count the 5 that is used and end the loop, and display a messageBox after stating how many textboxes were used.

// here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GPA_Calculator
{
    public partial class FormTitle : Form
    {
        public FormTitle()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Calculatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Declare variables
            double grade = 0.0;
            double total_grade = 0.0;
            double pre_gpa = 0.0;
            double gpa_result = 0.0;


            int class_one_textBox = 0;
            int class_two_textBox = 0;
            int class_three_textBox = 0;
            int class_four_textBox = 0;
            int class_five_textBox = 0;

            #region // Checks if all fields are empty
            if ((textBox1.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.SelectedText)) 
                && (textBox2.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.SelectedText)) 
                && (textBox3.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox3.SelectedText)) 
                && (textBox4.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox4.SelectedText))
                && (textBox5.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox5.SelectedText)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields!"); // Display message to user if field is empty
            }// end if
            #endregion

            **/*NEED A BETTER LOOP HERE*/**
            for (double i = 0; i <= total_grade.ToString().Count(); i++)
            {

                #region // Class 1 Calculations
                if ((comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1) && (textBox1.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                    || (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1) && (textBox1.Text.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Class 1 contains an empty field!");
                }
                else if ((comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1) && (textBox1.Text.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    {
                        case "A":
                            class_one_textBox = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                            grade = 4.00 * class_one_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "A-":
                            class_one_textBox = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                            grade = 3.67 * class_one_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B+":
                            class_one_textBox = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                            grade = 3.33 * class_one_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B":
                            class_one_textBox = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                            grade = 3.00 * class_one_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B-":
                            class_one_textBox = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                            grade = 2.67 * class_one_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C+":
                            class_one_textBox = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                            grade = 2.33 * class_one_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C":
                            class_one_textBox = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                            grade = 2.00 * class_one_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C-":
                            class_one_textBox = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                            grade = 1.67 * class_one_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "D":
                            class_one_textBox = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                            grade = 1.33 * class_one_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "F":
                            class_one_textBox = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                            grade = 1.00 * class_one_textBox;
                            break;
                    } // end switch
                } // end if
                #endregion


                #region // Class 2 Calculations
                if ((comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1) && (textBox2.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                    || (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == -1) && (textBox2.Text.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Class 2 contains an empty field!");
                }
                else if ((comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1) && (textBox2.Text.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    switch (comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    {
                        case "A":
                            class_two_textBox = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                            grade = 4.00 * class_two_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "A-":
                            class_two_textBox = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                            grade = 3.67 * class_two_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B+":
                            class_two_textBox = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                            grade = 3.33 * class_two_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B":
                            class_two_textBox = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                            grade = 3.00 * class_two_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B-":
                            class_two_textBox = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                            grade = 2.67 * class_two_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C+":
                            class_two_textBox = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                            grade = 2.33 * class_two_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C":
                            class_two_textBox = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                            grade = 2.00 * class_two_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C-":
                            class_two_textBox = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                            grade = 1.67 * class_two_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "D":
                            class_two_textBox = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                            grade = 1.33 * class_two_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "F":
                            class_two_textBox = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                            grade = 1.00 * class_two_textBox;
                            break;
                    } // end switch
                } // end if
                #endregion


                #region // Class 3 Calculations
                if ((comboBox3.SelectedIndex > -1) && (textBox3.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                    || (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == -1) && (textBox3.Text.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Class 3 contains an empty field!");
                }
                else if ((comboBox3.SelectedIndex > -1) && (textBox3.Text.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    switch (comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    {
                        case "A":
                            class_three_textBox = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                            grade = 4.00 * class_three_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "A-":
                            class_three_textBox = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                            grade = 3.67 * class_three_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B+":
                            class_three_textBox = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                            grade = 3.33 * class_three_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B":
                            class_three_textBox = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                            grade = 3.00 * class_three_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B-":
                            class_three_textBox = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                            grade = 2.67 * class_three_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C+":
                            class_three_textBox = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                            grade = 2.33 * class_three_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C":
                            class_three_textBox = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                            grade = 2.00 * class_three_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C-":
                            class_three_textBox = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                            grade = 1.67 * class_three_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "D":
                            class_three_textBox = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                            grade = 1.33 * class_three_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "F":
                            class_three_textBox = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                            grade = 1.00 * class_three_textBox;
                            break;
                    } // end switch
                } // end else/if
                #endregion


                #region // Class 4 Calculations
                if ((comboBox4.SelectedIndex > -1) && (textBox4.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                    || (comboBox4.SelectedIndex == -1) && (textBox4.Text.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Class 4 contains an empty field!");
                }
                else if ((comboBox4.SelectedIndex > -1) && (textBox4.Text.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    switch (comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    {
                        case "A":
                            class_four_textBox = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                            grade = 4.00 * class_four_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "A-":
                            class_four_textBox = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                            grade = 3.67 * class_four_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B+":
                            class_four_textBox = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                            grade = 3.33 * class_four_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B":
                            class_four_textBox = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                            grade = 3.00 * class_four_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B-":
                            class_four_textBox = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                            grade = 2.67 * class_four_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C+":
                            class_four_textBox = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                            grade = 2.33 * class_four_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C":
                            class_four_textBox = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                            grade = 2.00 * class_four_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C-":
                            class_four_textBox = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                            grade = 1.67 * class_four_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "D":
                            class_four_textBox = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                            grade = 1.33 * class_four_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "F":
                            class_four_textBox = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
                            grade = 1.00 * class_four_textBox;
                            break;
                    } // end switch
                } // end else if
                #endregion


                #region // Class 5 Calculations
                if ((comboBox5.SelectedIndex > -1) && (textBox5.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
                    || (comboBox5.SelectedIndex == -1) && (textBox5.Text.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Class 5 contains an empty field!");
                }
                else if ((comboBox5.SelectedIndex > -1) && (textBox5.Text.Trim() != string.Empty))
                {
                    switch (comboBox5.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    {
                        case "A":
                            class_five_textBox = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                            grade = 4.00 * class_five_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "A-":
                            class_five_textBox = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                            grade = 3.67 * class_five_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B+":
                            class_five_textBox = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                            grade = 3.33 * class_five_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B":
                            class_five_textBox = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                            grade = 3.00 * class_five_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "B-":
                            class_five_textBox = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                            grade = 2.67 * class_five_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C+":
                            class_five_textBox = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                            grade = 2.33 * class_five_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C":
                            class_five_textBox = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                            grade = 2.00 * class_five_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "C-":
                            class_five_textBox = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                            grade = 1.67 * class_five_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "D":
                            class_five_textBox = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                            grade = 1.33 * class_five_textBox;
                            break;
                        case "F":
                            class_five_textBox = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
                            grade = 1.00 * class_five_textBox;
                            break;
                    } // end switch
                } // end else if
                #endregion

                total_grade = total_grade + grade;
            }

            // Sums up the amount of credits
            pre_gpa = class_one_textBox + class_two_textBox + class_three_textBox
                + class_four_textBox + class_five_textBox;

            gpa_result = total_grade / pre_gpa;
            MessageBox.Show("Your GPA is " + gpa_result); // Displays GPA
```

Comment: What have you tried? We need to see that you've at least tried something first : )

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user has not entered text in all TextBoxes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a extension method to get the textboxes in the form.

```
public static IEnumerable<TControl> GetChildControls(this Control control) where TControl : Control
{
    var children = (control.Controls != null) ? control.Controls.OfType<TControl>() : Enumerable.Empty<TControl>();
    return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls(c)).Concat(children);
}
```

Get all the textboxes.

```
var allTextBoxes = this.GetChildControls<TextBox>();
```

check the value in each text box.

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (TextBox oTextBox in this.GetChildControls<TextBox>())
{
    if(oTextBox.Text != string.Empty)
       sum += 1;
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863138/1537422

Comment: What is the difference between getting the controls from your method, and getting the controls from `this.Controls`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use this.Controls

```
  int sum = 0;
  foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
  {
    if(tb.Text != string.Empty) //textbox is not empty do something
        sum += int.Parse(tb.Text);
    else break; // here you can detect if textbox is empty
  }
```

You can use this code in Load event of Form. The example above couts the sum of textboxes that are not empty and breaks the loop on first empty textbox. You can modify it not to break the loop but just don't count the empty textboxes.

To find TextBox recursively check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863051/loop-through-textboxes)

Comment: I assume that OP wants something different. _"the user entered values in 5 out of 8"_ I think that means that he wants to ensure that the user entered something in all 8 TextBoxes or at least that he wants to know the TextBoxes where the user entered text at all. Apart from that, `this.Controls.OfType` will not find controls recursively in child controls.

Comment: I just took a look, from my VS Controls doesn't even allow an OfType method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes you're right it won't find child items but [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863051/loop-through-textboxes) is example how to find textboxes recursively

Comment: @Shane.C add `using System.Linq` and reference to `System.Core.dll` and you will have it.

Comment: Strange, i thought it did, but VS didn't give it's usual "Add this namespace and it'll work". Sorry about that!

Comment: np is this solution what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0; // create counter
foreach (Control c in Controls) // start loop through all the controls in the current form
{
    if(!(c is TextBox)) continue; // if the control is not a TextBox, continue the loop
    TextBox t = c as TextBox; // redeclare
    if(t.Text != "") // if the text in the textbox is NOT empty
    {
        count++; // add to the counter
    }
} // end loop
if (count >= 5) // check if the counter is higher or equal than 5
{
    // do stuff!
}
```

I hope this helps you out. I haven't run it myself yet but it *should* work. (I hope!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
int cnt = 0;

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    if (c is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
            cnt++;
```