# How to change value of multiple textbox's

Tags: variables, textbox

I have about 30 textboxes on my form, and I want them to load "0.000" when the app loads. As it is now, I just have each one listed, Hows can i use a variable to call any textbox, or a "tagged" textbox so it will load what I want without having to list each one independently?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    SCutL.Text = "0.000"
    NeSize.Text = "0.000"
    StrHole.Text = "0.000"
    NeSpace.Text = "0.000"
```

Comment: When posting a question about your code, it's always a good idea to add a tag for the language you're using.

Comment: I tried to edit the tags, but it says I need a better reputation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count the number of textboxes used and use that value to end loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427033/count-the-number-of-textboxes-used-and-use-that-value-to-end-loop)

Comment: Just [edit] your post and add the tag. You can't edit tags without sufficient rep, but you can always edit your own question or answer.

Comment: I try to edit this listing and it wont let me choose "english" as a tag. it wants me to pick from an existing list of tags until I have a reputation of 1500.

Comment: LOL. Not the language you're writing your text in. The **programming language** you're using (C, VB.Net, C#, Java). We can read the words in your sentences to see what language you're using there. Adding a tag for the **language you're coding in** will get the question in front of the people who can answer it.