# I cannot iterate through textboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to iterate through the textboxes in my window so I can make operations on them. Here is my code:

```
foreach (Control c in Controls)
{
    if (c is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(c.Name);
    }
}
```

I have put a breakpoint on the line with `if`, my program reaches that breakpoint, but it doesn't reach the `MessageBox` line... Where is the error? (I tested this with `c is Button` and it worked...)

Comment: Are you sure the textboxes are *direct* children of the form? They're not (for example) on panels?

Comment: actually, they are child of panels... what can I do in this situation, because I also have many panels on this window...

Comment: @Victor `Recursive method` to loop through all the controls on your form is what you need.

Comment: then, can you post an answer?

Comment: @Victor maybe one of the answers below can help you.

Comment: Refer to the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863051/loop-through-textboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly so simple that I don't want to add an answer, but for the OP's request:

```
private void CheckTextBoxesName(Control root){
    foreach(Control c in root.Controls){
        if(c is TextBox) MessageBox.Show(c.Name);
        CheckTextBoxesName(c);
    }
}
//in your form scope call this:
CheckTextBoxesName(this);
//out of your form scope:
CheckTextBoxesName(yourForm);
//Note that, if your form has a TabControl, it's a little particular to add more code, otherwise, it's almost OK with the code above.
```

Comment: I know how to call it :p

Comment: @Victor see my edit, it's simple.

Comment: @keyboardP :)) a humorous downvoter?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you

```
    foreach (TextBox t in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
         MessageBox.Show(t.Name);
    }
```

Alternative :

```
void TextBoxesName(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        TextBox textBox = child as TextBox;
        if (textBox == null)
            ClearTextBoxes(child);
        else
            MessageBox.Show(textbox.Name);
    }
}

    TextBoxesName(this);
```

Comment: The first code can't work in the case of the OP, we have only 1 solution in which we use recursive method.

Comment: @KingKing, post an answer if you know it!