# How to use variable names that are created in a loop and stored in List<string>?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a List object that gets automatically filled with the names of textboxes. Now I'd like to cycle through all these text boxes.
How can I let C# know that the string-names in the List are actually TextBox objects with that string-name?

```
        List<string> txtOppsNames = new List<string>(); 
        for (int i = 1; i < numOpps; i++) 
        {
            txtOppsNames.Add("txtOpp" + i);
        }
        foreach (var txtName in txtOppsNames) 
        {
            if (txtName.Text != "")
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
```

The current code reads txtName as a string. I would like it to read as a TextBox.

Edit - the below code contains the solution for me.

```
        List<string> txtOppsNames = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i < numOpps; i++) 
        {
            txtOppsNames.Add("txtOpp" + i);
        }
        foreach (var txtName in txtOppsNames)
        {
            TextBox textBox = this.Controls.Find(txtName, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
            if (textBox.Text != "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Thanks Amir Popovich");
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can't do that, what environment are you working in? ASP.NET / Windows Forms etc.

Comment: `txtOppsNames` is a `List<string>`. Why do you think your `txtName` can be a `TextBox`?

Comment: You could consider creating the textboxes dynamically (not via designer), and add them to a `List<TextBox>` instead.

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms application. I'm used to doing similar operations in VBA-code, I'd love to use it in this environment.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the text? and how are you filling the list? its possible that you could use data-binding or just use a `TextBox` list as previously suggested to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @Paretozen - two things:
1. change `if (textBox.Text != "")` to `if(textBox != null && textBox.Text != string.Empty)` since you are using `FirstOrDefault`.
2. You don't need to edit your question and add the answer- You need to accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Control.ControlCollection.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
string textBoxName = "txtOpp1";
TextBox textBox = this.Controls.Find(textBoxName, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
```

In your case:

```
List<string> txtOppsNames = new List<string>(); 
for (int i = 1; i < numOpps; i++) 
{
    txtOppsNames.Add("txtOpp" + i);
}
foreach (var txtName in txtOppsNames) 
{
   var control = this.Controls.Find(txtName, true).FirstOrDefault();
   if(control != null && control is TextBox)
   {
      TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;
      if(textBox.Text != string.Empty)
      {
          //logic
      }
   } 
 }
```

Comment: I like @Royi's answer, as it has the test to ensure it is a textbox, but I also like your `textBox.Text !=string.Empty.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  List<string> txtOppsNames = new List<string>(); 
        for (int i = 1; i < numOpps; i++) 
        {
            txtOppsNames.Add("txtOpp" + i);
        }
        foreach (var txtName in txtOppsNames) 
        {
          var cntrl= FindControl(txtName);
           if (cntrl!=null && cntrl is TextBox)
              // do something with 
              ((TextBox)cntrl)
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is Winform, There seems to be no pretty way to do it.

But you could use [Loop through Textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863051/loop-through-textboxes).

once you have the text box collection, check the names with your string.