# FindControl perfomance when adding sqlparameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have about 65 textbox fields in my ASP.NET form. 
Instead of adding all parameters to `SqlCommand` one by one, I want to do like this.

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    string[] fields = { "EmployeeID", "EmployeeNumber", "FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName" };
    foreach (string fld in fields)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)Page.FindControl(fld); 
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + fld, tb.Text ); 
    }
}
```

Is it a good idea to use `FindControl` method when considering performance for this type of scenario.

Comment: Don't know if there is a real performance impact due to FindControl. But I could suggest something else : if all Textboxes are in a common container, you can also loop other them using its Controls property. It avoids use of FindControl and doesn't require anymore the fields[] variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding all the textboxes from your page you can only loop through the textbox controls like this:-

```
foreach (TextBox textbox in Page.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{
            //Your Code here
}
```

But I am really note sure how much of performance gain you will get out of it when compared to that of `FindControl`.

Also, as @AFract mentioned since Control collection is not recursive, to get all the controls recursively you can use this very helpful extension method:-

```
public static IEnumerable<TControl> GetChildControls(this Control control) where TControl : Control
{
    var children = (control.Controls != null) ? control.Controls.OfType<TControl>() : Enumerable.Empty<TControl>();
    return children.SelectMany(c => GetChildControls(c)).Concat(children);
}
```

Borrowed from [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863138/1529657).

Comment: It's what I've also suggested in my comment. One thing to know : Controls collection is not recursive, so if Textboxes are not directly in Page itself, they won't be found. But this could easily be fixed.

Comment: @AFract - Yeah Exactly.