# Loop through sequential control names C#

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop, foreach

I wish to assign values to NumericUpDowns which are named `numericUpDown1`, `numericUpDown2`, etc. What I wish to achieve is something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < readBuf.Length; i++)
{
    numericUpDown[i + 1].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(BitConverter.ToSingle(readBuf[i], startIndex: 0));             
}
```

What I tried doing is the method described here: [Loop through Textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863051/loop-through-textboxes), but it doesn't give the expected results when I use it like this

```
var allNumUpDwn = this.GetChildControls<NumericUpDown>();
int i = 0;
foreach (NumericUpDown nud in allNumUpDwn)
{
    nud.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(BitConverter.ToSingle(readBuf[i], startIndex: 0));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What exactly the `readBuf` is? You have to debug your application. Insert breakpoints in the code and see what's going on.

Comment: @Dmitry I am reading memory from another process and changing it with a numericUpDown control, but sometimes the values change in the program and the numericUpDowns doesn't update so I need to read the memory again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use this kind of approach:

```
var nuds = new []
{
    numericUpDown1, numericUpDown2,
    numericUpDown3, numericUpDown4,
    numericUpDown5, numericUpDown6,
    // etc
};

for (int i = 0; i < readBuf.Length; i++)
{
    nuds[i].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(BitConverter.ToSingle(readBuf[i], startIndex: 0));
}
```

The big advantage here is that your code is compile-time checked, so that if you start deleting or renaming controls then you will have a compile error rather than a run-time error.

Comment: I agree with Enigmativity. This approach is better unless your numericUpDowns are built dynamically.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ah I was hoping I could avoid the repetitiveness of writing each numericUpDown in an array, but if it's what needs to be done, it has to be done. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: @RikusHoney - You could always collect the array using `Controls.Find` and LINQ, but that would return you to a run-time error if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < readBuf.Length; i++)
{
    ((NumericUpDown)Controls.Find("numericUpDown" + (i+1))).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(BitConverter.ToSingle(readBuf[i], startIndex: 0));             
}
```