# How do I use a C# Foreach loop to insert records into a database?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, loops, foreach

I'm currently working on a project where I've been asked to work on a WPF with the following requirements:

1. Allow the user to be able to add more textboxes in a stack panel
2. Save the user input (as string/nvarchar) in each textbox as a new record in 
   the database

The idea behind this is that if we receive multiple packages, each shipment is typically split up into multiple locations and we'd need to located where each component is.

I've included a sample of my code below, its barebones and will probably have more than just the one 'Records' field things will be inserted into. I've set the RecordID field to being an identity field so I'm not worried about declaring the ID field. It's not included in the sample but each record is linked to a ShipmentID.

I'd appreciate any help as I've been having trouble implementing it (and have hit a wall with my research) as my code runs into a:

'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll' with the CommandText Property not initialized error, when I try I try to save the record. I've unfortunately found only vague tidbits how to solve my issue (or maybe I'm just terrible at research).

```
    private void StackAddTB(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox NewBox = new TextBox() { Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0), Width = 100, Height = 20 };
        StackBoxes.Children.Add(NewBox);
    }

    private void SaveMulti(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string CStr = Manifesting.Properties.Settings.Default.PSIOpsSurfaceCS;
        SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(CStr);
        string Query = "INSERT INTO TestLoop (Record), Values (Record)";
        SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection)

        foreach (TextBox TestTB in StackBoxes.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            try
            {
                Connection.Open();
                Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
                Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Record", TestTB.Text );
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Edit: I've checked through the Looping Through Textbox question (as per mr. reds comment), and while I've found some things useful from the other post it does not go into detail in how those values are saved in a db.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through Textboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863051/loop-through-textboxes)

Comment: instead of `Connection.Open()` and all the other Connection code you need to be using the instance of your SqlConnection object `SqlConnection.Open();` also you should open the connection before the loop, then wrap your connection in a `using()` statement and you won't have to close it manually.

Comment: Extra comma. string Query = "INSERT INTO TestLoop (Record) -->,<-- Values (Record)";

Comment: @prospector thank you for the tip!

Comment: @AndrewHarris, I've made edits to the syntax but Im sadly still running into the same error

Comment: You need to open the connection outside of the foreach loop. You don't want to keep connecting to the database just to insert one record.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, this is how I would structure your code.

```
    private void SaveMulti(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string CStr = Manifesting.Properties.Settings.Default.PSIOpsSurfaceCS;
        string Query = "INSERT INTO TestLoop (Record) Values (@Record)";
        string Record = StackBoxes.Children.OfType<TextBox>().ToString();

        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(CStr))
        {
            foreach (TextBox TestTB in StackBoxes.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Removed as pointed out by EJoshuaS
                        //cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Record", TestTB.Text);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Next, what is the purpose of this line?

```
string Record = StackBoxes.Children.OfType<TextBox>().ToString();
```

Comment: I'm not sitting in front of an IDE, but I think that this will have the same exact problem as the OP's original code.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Note the fact they were opening and closing the connection but reusing the command. He was also missing the @ before Record so no parameter existed for the "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Record", TestTB.Text);" line.

Comment: Just saw your answer...Yes you are right...Should have picked that up.

Comment: @AndrewHarris thank you for your comments thus far. Just to clear things up the string record = stackboxes.etc line was intended to take the TestTB.Text spot in the parameter but it didn't work either. I'll edit the post to remove it. Cheers

Comment: @AndrewHarris I've re-edited the format in my IDE based on your respective and it works now. Thank you very much for helping this rookie programmer! :)

Comment: @EJoshuaS Thank you for your comments, your input + mr andrew's comments solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
 Command = Connection.CreateCommand();
  Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Record", TestTB.Text );
  Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You "clobber" whatever was in `Command` before, so you never specify anywhere what the actual query is. That's why it gives you the exception - you literally give it no query to run.

Note that this line:

```
 SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);
```

currently makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: thanks for informing me of this. I'll make some changes and hope that it'll fix my issue.