# want to use a Lable with a variable

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use a loop and go through different labels with only a numerical difference (Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4, Num5). Is it possible to cycle through these using a loop?

this is what I have:

```
foreach (int Numer in lotoNums) 
   ("Num" + Numer.ToString()).Text = lotoNums[Numer].ToString();
```

*"Num"* is the shared label name where *"Numer"* is the number label I want. also *"lotoNums"* has a length of 5.

I haven't seen any post asking this, but if there is one please say so!

Comment: What is `lotoNums`? An array? A dictionary?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen 'lotonums' is an array.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863138/3791245) help you get started?  Your syntax as written won't work for accessing any Label UI elements. (A `string` cannot be implicitly cast to a `Label`.)

Comment: You're already referencing `lotoNums` correctly as a collection, why can't the `"Num..."` values also be in a collection?  Alternatively, if these are UI control elements you're looking for, you can [find controls by name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3898588/328193).

Comment: Can you add a tag for the framework you are using?