# Get value from multiple TextBox elements

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a few different TextBox elements named as followed "e0", "e1", "e2", "e3". I know how many there are and I just want to be able to loop through them and grab their values rather than typing each one out manually.

I'm assuming I'll be doing something like this, I just don't know how to access the element.

```
for(int i= 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    string name = "e" + i;
    // How do I use my newly formed textbox name to access the textbox 
    // element in winforms?
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/c-sharp-get-control-by-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against this approach since it's prone to errors. What if you want to rename them, what if you'll forget about this and add other controls with name `e...`?

Instead i would collect them in a container control like [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx).
Then you can use `LINQ` to find the relevant `TextBoxes`:

```
var myTextBoxes = myPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
```

`Enumerable.OfType` will filter and cast the controls accordingly. If you want to filter them more, you could use `Enumerable.Where`, for example:

```
var myTextBoxes = myPanel.Controls
                         .OfType<TextBox>()
                         .Where(txt => txt.Name.ToLower().StartsWith("e"));
```

Now you can iterate those `TextBoxes`, for example:

```
foreach(TextBox txt in myTextBoxes)
{
    String text = txt.Text;
    // do something amazing
}
```

**Edit**:

> The TextBoxes are on multiple TabPages. Also, the names are a little
>   more logical ...

This approach works also when the controls are on multiple tabpages, for example:

```
var myTextBoxes = from tp in tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>()
                  from panel in tp.Controls.OfType<Panel>()
                  where panel.Name.StartsWith("TextBoxGroup")
                  from txt in panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                  where txt.Name.StartsWith("e")
                  select txt;
```

<sub>(note that i've added another condition that the panels names' must start with `TextBoxGroup`, just to show that you can also combine the conditions)</sub>

Of course the way to detect the relevant controls can be changed as desired(f.e. with `RegularExpression`).

Comment: While this solution is very nice I don't think it would work for this application :( The TextBoxes are on multiple TabPages. Also, the names are a little more logical than e[x] but I figured it wouldn't really matter for an example. Thanks for this :D If I can figure out how to re-org things without upsetting people I might do this.

Comment: @AngeloR.: This approach works also when the controls are on multiple tabpages. See my edit.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the update Tim. I'm not too familiar with LINQ so I never even realized that it could be used for something like this. I've changed this to be the actual answer because it seems to be a little more robust, and cause it taught me a bit about LINQ :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use parent of your controls like this(Assuming you have placed all controls in the form, so I have used this)

```
for(int i= 0; i < 4; ++i) {
string name = "e" + i;
TextBox txtBox=this.Controls[name] as TextBox;
Console.Writeline(txtBox.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
this.Controls.Find()

for(int i= 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    string name = "e" + i;
    TextBox txtBox = this.Controls.Find(name) as TextBox;
}
```

Or this :

```
this.Controls["name"]

for(int i= 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    string name = "e" + i;
    TextBox txtBox = this.Controls[name] as TextBox;
}
```