# Else If, Error Checking Done More Efficiently?

Tags: c#, winforms

What's a more efficient way to error check my UI without copy/pasting the same code over and over again?

I'm currently using repetitive else if () statements and I'm sure they're a more efficient way of doing it. I thought about using for loops but the different UI names makes it hard to implement into a for loop.

```
private void BoatSubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (BoatNameTextBox.Text == "")
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input Name", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    else if (Catch1ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount1.Value == 0)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    else if (Catch2ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount2.Value == 0 
        )
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    else if (Catch3ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount3.Value == 0)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    else if (Catch4ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount4.Value == 0)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

An even more efficient way of error checking is using OR in the condition for example:

```
else if (Catch1ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount1.Value == 0 ||
Catch2ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount2.Value == 0 ||
Catch3ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount3.Value == 0 ||
Catch4ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount4.Value == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Use a method or delegate of some type rather than copying and pasting the code. If the list of conditions is likely to change/grow, you could change them into a list of delegates that when evaluated to true, execute the method that displays the MessageBox

Comment: What is the original `if` for these `else if`s?  And are there more `else if`s not shown?

Comment: wher is this code situated? in an event handler? `SelectedIndexChanged` ? or some ClickHandler?

Comment: why do you output in all cases the same message?

Comment: @Mong Zhu The statements are in a button_click event handler

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260681/get-value-from-multiple-textbox-elements is likely what you are looking for... also "more efficient" is really unclear explanation of what you trying to achieve making the question poor fit for SO.

Comment: You could put the combination of a combobox and the corresponding numericUpDown into a groupbox, then put all those 4 group boxes into a single groupbox. Then you could iterate over the controls of the most outer groupbox and check it for every pair of combobox and numericUpDown. Alternatively to the loop you could also use `OfType` and Linq

Comment: @elmer007 I've updated the post which includes the things you've asked

Comment: are you looking for a way to decrease the amount of code for such a case? do you intend to extend the amount of comboboxes and numericUpDowns?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes that's right, I'm trying to decrease the amount of code I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer to wrap condition in a method and then pass my values to it in only one `if statement`:

```
public static bool Check(ComboBox combo, NumericUpDown amount)
{
    if (combo.SelectedIndex != -1 && amount.Value == 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

And then call `Check` method this way:

```
if (!Check(Catch1ComboBox, NumericAmount1) || !Check(Catch2ComboBox, NumericAmount2) ||
   !Check(Catch3ComboBox, NumericAmount3) || !Check(Catch4ComboBox, NumericAmount4))
   MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

In more complicated problems it's better to use [Rules design pattern](http://www.michael-whelan.net/rules-design-pattern/).

Comment: `NumericAmount amount)` NumericAmount is underlined with an error stating - `The type or namespace could not be found` Any ideas?

Comment: What is the type of NumericAmount?

Comment: It's a NumericUpDown box

Comment: Change the `NumericAmount` in Check method to `NumericUpDown` as I did in answer.

Answer (score 2):

With an array of [ValueTuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/) (C# 7.0) you can make it like this:

```
if (BoatNameTextBox.Text == "") {
    MessageBox.Show("Please Input Name", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
} else {
    (ComboBox cbo, NumericUpDown nud)[] input = {
        (Catch1ComboBox, NumericAmount1),
        (Catch2ComboBox, NumericAmount2),
        (Catch3ComboBox, NumericAmount3),
        (Catch4ComboBox, NumericAmount4)
    };

    if (input.Any(x => x.cbo.SelectedIndex != -1 && x.nud.Value == 0)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

You could also make the array a class field and set it up in the constructor.

Comment: Named tuples ! That's a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you use `else if` if you need to do *different things* for each case. If you need to do the *same thing*, then I would combine all the cases into one, and just split them up with line breaks to make it easier to read:

```
else if ((Catch1ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount1.Value == 0) ||
         (Catch2ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount2.Value == 0) ||
         (Catch3ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount3.Value == 0) ||
         (Catch4ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount4.Value == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

*Edit:* Which, I now see you added to your question....

I wouldn't bother with loops or anything unless you had a lot more of these. If there really are only 4, then I would leave it be.

Answer (score 0):

EDit: sorry typo in signature

You could clean it up by adding an extension method

```
public static void isSelected(this ComboBox comboBox){
       return comboBox.SelectedIndex != -1;
} 

public static bool IsZero(this NumericAmount amt){
       return amt.Value == 0;
} //or w/e type NumericAmount actually is
```

THen in your if/else

```
if ((!Catch1ComboBox.isSelected() && NumericAmount1.IsZero()) ||
         (!Catch2ComboBox.isSelected() && NumericAmount2.IsZero()) ||
         (!Catch3ComboBox.isSelected()  && NumericAmount3.IsZero()) ||
         (!Catch4ComboBox.isSelected() && NumericAmount4.IsZero())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure in winforms you can also select all 4 of those like html classes and run the extension method, that way you only have 1 validation call for each class.

Answer (score 0):

When logic gets complicated, sometimes it better to flip the logic into their own *evaluators* (as [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.8)).  It provides a much easier way to read and maintain specific errors, and reduces the whole `if, else` repetition.

```cs
var List<Func<bool>> hasInputFishErrorConditions = new List<Func<bool>>()
{
  () => Catch1ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount1.Value == 0,
  () => Catch2ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && NumericAmount2.Value == 0,
  // etc
};
```

Then it's the code looks like:

```cs
var hasInputFishError = hasInputFishErrorConditions.Any();

if (hasInputFishError) {
 MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught",
        "ERROR", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    };
} else {
  // no error condition
}
```

Comment: I think you missed that the `SelectedIndex != -1` comparisons were using different combo boxes.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I did totally miss that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to have some validation framework, but I often use a loop when such a case arise:

```
var myCombos = new[] { Catch1ComboBox, Catch2ComboBox, Catch3ComboBox, Catch4ComboBox };
var myNumTextboxes = new [] { NumericAmount1, NumericAmount2, NumericAmount3, NumericAmount4 };

foreach(var x in myCombos.Zip(myNumTextboxes, (combo, numtextbox) => new { combo, numtextbox })) {
    if(x.combo.SelectedIndex != -1 && x.numtextbox.Value == 0) {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input Amount Of Fish Caught", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        break;
    }
}
```

}