# C# Get SelectedIndex in ComboBox by name

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have to process some controls by their names

```
this.Controls.Find(String.Format("lbl{0}", index),
            true)[0].Text = data[i].ToString();
```

but when I tryed to get a Combobox by name it can't show the SelectedIndex property

```
this.Controls.Find(String.Format("cmbDat{0}", index), true)[0].
```

Who i can do?

Comment: What has to do the Find method with the SelectedIndex property of a combobox? You don't use any SelectedIndex property in the code above

Comment: -.- I can't use a SelectedIndex property in the code above because intellisense don't show this option in my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast it to a `ComboBox`, because `Find()` returns a `Control`, which does not contain the `SelectedIndex` property.

Try this instead:

```
ComboBox theComboBox = this.Controls.Find(String.Format("cmbDat{0}", index), true) as ComboBox;

// Verify the combo box was found before trying to use it
if(theComboBox != null)
{
    // Do whatever you want with the combo box here
    theComboBox.SelectedIndex = ???
    theComboBox.Text = ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way looks easier https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639106/12537158, all you need is this line:

```
Control ctn = this.Controls[name];
```