# Change Name of a Control within a command

Tags: c#, variables

I am trying to build a navigation system and includes a back button. The back button when clicked makes the last visible panel visible again.

The back button is a linklabel which executes the below line.

```
_backLocation.visible= true;
```

`_backLocation` is a string variable that contains the panel name that was last visible. Once the user navigates away from a panel that panel is made invisible.

However the above line isn't valid code and doesn't compile. Is there a way to achieve this simple solution or maybe a better way?

Comment: Why use a `String` variable in the first place?  Why not use a variable that you can assign the `Panel` itself to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either save the last visible control in a `private Control _previousControl` or [find the control by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be simple. I didn't know you could declare as a Control.