# Changing picturebox backcolor in Visual Studio (c#) using a variable in place of a name

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to make a simple game using a 10x10 grid of empty pictureboxes, and I've run into a very specific problem.

The idea is that the application makes a calculation based on player input and changes the backcolor of specific pictureboxes in the grid. Though how exactly that works isn't really important to this question.

The pictureboxes are named `pictureBox1, pictureBox2, etc.` (All the way up to 100).

I know that I can change the backcolor with this line of code:

```
pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(int, int, int);
```

Now let's say the application returns the variable `int resultValue = 25`, which means that I want pictureBox25 to change its `Backcolor`.
Now, if I could just write the code like this:

```
string pbName = "pictureBox" + resultValue.toString();

pbName.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(int, int, int);
```

...then there wouldn't be a problem. But Visual Studio doesn't seem to accept a string varable in place of a name.

Is there any type of variable it would accept, or is there another way to accomplish what I need without resorting to a giant if-statement.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp to find a control by name.

Comment: Additionally, this is probably the least efficient way to make a game like this. You should really draw the grid yourself, would make things a lot easier and faster than PictureBox controls...

Comment: If sticking to the basic design, you ought to to put references to the pixtureboxes in a 2d array upon setup. Using a DataGridView would be even simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Control []controls=this.Controls.Find("pictureBox" + resultValue.ToString(), true);
        if (controls != null && controls.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (Control control in controls)
            {
                if (control.GetType() == typeof(PictureBox))
                {
                    PictureBox pictureBox = control as PictureBox;
                    pictureBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                }
            }
        }
```