# Check if a box with same Design (Name) exists?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new in c# and Visual Studio (2015). I want to create new box but before that i want to check if there is a box with the name of new box of not. I am struggling with what command to use to check if text box exits. I tried TextBox.Exits but there is nothing in directory.
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a Windows Forms control by name in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for specific controls that exist in your current form using the `Controls.Find` method (see [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(VS.80).aspx)). This will either return the control(s) that have been found in a `Control[]` array and in case nothing has been found, it will return and empty `Control[]` array.

In you case you can check on the array. If it's empty you know there's no `controls` yet with the name you want to use!

```
var controlFound = this.Controls.Find(NameYouWantToUseAndCheck, true);

if(controlFound.Length == 0)
{
    // No existing control has been found with this name, you can safely make your new control
}
else
{
    // An existing control has been found with this name, use another name or do whatever you want!
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much