# Create a procedure to reduce redundant code in C#

Tags: c#

When I click a check box on a Windows Form, it enables a text box and sets the cursor in it ready for input. Code is relatively simple:

```
private void chkLatte_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(chkLatte.Checked)
        {
            txtLatte.Enabled = true;
            txtLatte.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            txtLatte.Enabled = false;
            txtLatte.Text = "0";
        }
    }
```

Now, here's the rub. I have lots of these check boxes so what I want is something like this:

```
 public void setCheckBox(string chkName, string txtName)
    {

        if (chkName.Checked)
        {
            txtName.Enabled = true;
            txtName.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            txtName.Enabled = false;
            txtName.Text = "0";
        }
    }
```

Now, I can just call the method and pass the appropriate parameters like this:

```
  private void chkMocha_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setCheckBox(chkMocha,txtMocha);
    }
```

Of course, this won't work: .Checked .Enabled .Focus() etc only work with a check box object and I define chkName as a string

How should I re-write the procedure setCheckBox to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And why don't you pass the object sender as it is?

I mean something like this:

```
public void setCheckBox(CheckBox chk, TextBox txt)
{

    if (chk.Checked)
    {
        txt.Enabled = true;
        txt.Focus();
    }
    else
    {
        txt.Enabled = false;
        txt.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

And casting of course:

In the designer you have something like:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtMocha;
```

And by this reason you will solve a lot problems.

```
private void chkMocha_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setCheckBox((CheckBox)sender, txtMocha);
}
```

Also, I have to say, that the code you give doesn't work... You have supposed it.

If you want pass the parameters as strings, use this:

[Get a Windows Forms control by name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to assign the same handler to all checkboxes even

```
checkbox1.Check += chk_CheckedChanged;
checkbox2.Check += chk_CheckedChanged;
private void chk_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do your logic here
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the Original question: the single handler has no way of knowing which textBox to act upon, unless the logic has a way of deducing that from the identity of the sender. Such a mechanism  (e.g. a Dictionary linking CheckBoxes to TextBoxes) should be part of your solution to make it complete...