# How to open new user control from another user control in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

I create 2 menus (one for admin and another for user) those two menus are user controls, and I have a panel which will shows all content (Other user control) ..

userControl 1 is : Admin_menu

Button1          : button in Admin_menu

Button2          : button in Admin_menu

userControl 3 is : content1

userControl 4 is : content2

I have a main form that contains two sides : 
left side : Admin_menu 
right side : panel where the content will shows up

All the userControls are added to main form

the problem is : when I click on a button1 for showing content1, or button2 for showing content2 , I get this message :

[Problem pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqJlI.jpg)

My code in Admin_menu.cs :

```
        public Admin_menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnTrainers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Parent.Controls["trainersTab1"].BringToFront();
        }

        private void btnBranches_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //BranchesTab branchespage = new BranchesTab();
            //this.Parent.Controls.Add(branchespage);
            Parent.Controls["branchespage"].BringToFront();
        }

        private void btnTimeTables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Parent.Controls["timeTableTab1"].BringToFront();
        }
```

Comment: Controls `trainersTab1`, `branchespage` are added to `Admin_Menu` as part of `InitializeComponent` code? Are they added directly to the `Admin_Menu` or they are part of some container control such as Group Box or Panel in `Admin_Menu`? Are you using correct names of the controls to find them?

Comment: Highly likely you cannot get the "trainersTab" by Parent.Controls["trainersTab1"].

Best to use Visual Studio Watch window to see what objects are in Parents.Controls

Remember, there is a hierarchy of control you might need to go through

My best guess is to try
Parent.Controls["Admin_Menu"].Controls["trainersTab1"].BringToFront()

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have a main form that contains two sides :
left side : Admin_menu
right side : panel where the content will shows up 

all the userControls are added to main form

Answer (score 0):

Most likely

```
Parent.Controls["trainersTab1"]
```

is returning null.

This answer might help you find the trainerTab1 control, assuming the name of the control is also call "trainerTab1".

[Get a Windows Forms control by name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp)

```
Control trainerTab1 = this.Controls.Find("trainerTab1", true);
if (trainerTab1 != null) trainerTab1.BringToFront();
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I get an error at this line :
Control trainerTab1 = this.Controls.Find("trainerTab1", true);

error : cannot implicitly convert type 'system.windows.forms.control[] ' to 'system.windows.forms.control'

Comment: Sorry, forgot that the Controls.Find return Control[]

using System.Linq
...
if (trainerTab1 != null && trainerTab1.Any())
trainerTab1.First().BringToFront();