# how to make different panels with same conduct?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I'm making 10x10 cube with panels and the panels needs to change color when you click X times the panel but the code is so large, Is there another way for the code not to be so long?

This is my code:

```
int cont1 = 0, cont2 = 0, cont3 = 0, cont4 = 0, cont5 = 0, cont6 = 0, cont7 = 0, cont8 = 0, cont9 = 0, cont10 = 0;
```

then the event to change de color(All of my Panels have the same code but difference is "cont" and panel name):

```
 private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            cont1++;
            if (cont1 <= 5)
            {
                panel1.BackColor = Color.SlateBlue;
            }
            if (cont1 >=5)
            {
                panel1.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
            } 
            if (cont1 >= 10)
            {
                panel1.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            }
            if (cont1 >= 15)
            {
                panel1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            if (cont1 >= 20)
            {
                panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            } 
        }

//other panel 
private void panel2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            cont2++;
            if (cont2 <= 5)
            {
                panel2.BackColor = Color.SlateBlue;
            }
            if (cont2 >= 5)
            {
                panel2.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
            }
            if (cont2 >= 10)
            {
                panel2.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            }
            if (cont2 >= 15)
            {
                panel2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            if (cont2 >= 20)
            {
                panel2.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

note: Each panel changes its color, not all at the same time
Actually work with 4x4 but 10x10 is large for me

Comment: Hint: Put the panels into an array and use a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to create large amount of variables because you need to keep track of control states. You can leverage the existence of [control Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.8) and cut down the amount of code you write.

> Be it 1000 x 1000 panels the below method would work flawlessly for your usecase. All you need do is
>   point all target panel `mouseClick` to it and allow it handle the rest.

```
private void panel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = sender as Control;

    //get previous value from control tag or start at 0
    int count = ctrl.Tag == null ? 0 : (int)ctrl.Tag;

    //set backcolor of control based on tag number             
    if (count >= 20) ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
    else if (count >= 15) ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow; 
    else if (count >= 10) ctrl.BackColor = Color.Lime;
    else if (count >= 5)  ctrl.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
    else ctrl.BackColor = Color.SlateBlue; 

   // if (count == xx)
    //{// you may want to reset count after a certain number. Do that here...}

    ctrl.Tag = ++count;
}
```

Comment: if i want add a label to count the clicks on panel i can add `label1.Text = count.ToString();`? but the problem of large code is the same

Comment: You can make the names of labels relative to their panel. For example: `panel1` can have a label named `panel1_label` and `panel2` would have `panel2_label` then at the end of `MouseClick` function you can find the label using the `ctrl.Name` append with the word `_label` to get the target label for the panel. For more info about finding controls with name [see this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639106/8043806). Ask a new question if this solves your problem.

Comment: if i can add in the same mouse event on panel? because i need implement when you click in the panel inside have label who show the number of clicks?

Comment: I think that is a different question than the initial. You might want to ask that as a new question to get the solution as an answer.

Comment: ok i do that, but you can explain me this: your example in `book isTag Parse = Int64.TryParse(ctrl.Tag, out count);` the convert doesn't work because "object" cannot covert in "string"

Comment: Call `.ToString()` on Tag before parsing. See update

Comment: i'm getting two error the "if" is invalid because c# expect ; and out count show me "out int" cant convert in "out long"

Comment: Change int64 to int32. Remove condition from if braces,  see update

Comment: Thanks to boxing, the `Tag` property is perfectly capable of holding `int` values directly. Converting to and from string is insane.

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor this to use a method where you pass in the specific panel object and the current count value, rather than repeating the same logic over and over:

```
    private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        cont1++;
        updateColour(panel1, cont1);
    }

    //other panel 
    private void panel2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        cont2++;
        updateColour(panel2, cont2);
    }

    private void updateColour(Control ctrl, int count)
    {
        if (count >= 20)
        {
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else if (count >= 15)
        {
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        else if (count >= 10)
        {
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        }
        else if (count >= 5)
        {
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
        }
        else
        {
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.SlateBlue;
        }
    }
```

Note 1: I also re-wrote the count-checking logic so that it didn't unnecessarily paint the panel (up to) 4 different colours, instead it will always paint it just once. (In your previous logic, if the count was 21, it would first set the panel to Cyan (because 21 >= 5), then Lime (because 21 is also >= 10), and so on until the last `if`).

Note 2: Since BackColor is [actually a property of the parent `Control` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor?view=netframework-4.8), you could use this updateColour function with any control, not just a Panel)

In general in your code, if you find yourself repeating the same basic logic more than once, that usually means it's time to turn that logic into a separate method which can then be re-used across your application.

There is likely to be more refactoring you can do here (e.g. putting the panels and related counts into a data structure which links them together, and then using only one "click" handler method for all the panels, and using the `sender` to determine which panel was clicked) - but my example should reduce quite a large amount of your repetition.

Comment: ooh! thaks!, but if my cube is 10x10 i need like 100 count right? i can apply other thing to make more smaller?

Comment: Potentially yes - see my latest edit. I'll leave that as an exercise for you to try and figure out the exact code to make it work. Ask again if you get stuck.