# Using For loop to change combo box value

Tags: c#

I have list of 20 combo box NAME: combobox1z to combobox20z. I want to set text of those combobox via list and for loop, and don't know if it is possible like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
{
    comboxbox[i]z.Text = stringlist[i];
}
```

Comment: `WinForms`, `WPF` or...?

Comment: I don't really like to duplicate the same code 20 times because of the combox[i]z name is unique and can't put in loop.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
{
    this.Controls["comboxbox" + i.ToString() + "z"]?.Text = stringlist[i];
}` quick and dirty if using `WinForms`.

Comment: For winforms look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a Windows Forms control by name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: yes, WinForm. let me try your code. but how is it dirty you mean ?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  - That would only work if the ComboBoxes aren't inside another control. You may to drill down recursively to get all the ComboBoxes.

Comment: @Frank Ball of course, but we dont have that information to know that.

Comment: @Jackie there's other ways to do it and its a general response enough to get you started. For example, are these combobox's in other controls, if so, you would need recursion to dig down.

Comment: yes @Çöđěxěŕ, i tried your code, it works properly.
but my case is the combo box in inside the groupbox and it not work anymore.
Could you show me the general way to get it ?

Comment: corrected, @FrankBall. my case is the ComboBoxes inside the GroupBox.
is there the general way to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

**

### try this

**

for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)

{

```
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();

comboBox = this.Controls.Find("comboxbox" + i.ToString()+"Z", false)[0];

   for (int y = 1; y < 21; y++)

   {

       comboBox1.Items.Add (stringlist[y]);

   }
```

}