# asp.net c# I need to access value of a variable from the variable name stored in another string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please note:- I already have gone few links answered but they are leading to controls only. I can use objects easily to access into objects, no issues about that. Issue is with variables accessing at runtime. One is directing to variable, but I found it very tough and rigid one. So want to know any simple and easy way.

I have a requirement following:-

Scenario for e.g.:-

```
 1. TextBox_mobile is a control object in aspx page
 2. mobile is a variable stored in c# .cs file
 3. I have a 135+ such controls in aspx page and want to store them in variables in .cs file on say submit button.
 4. I have stored in a table having two fields control_objects and against it variable names
 5. So when submitt is fired (click event) I want to run the assigning task with running a process to retriew control names and
variables names and assinging the values of control objects to appropriate variables.
```

For e.g. to more going in practical:-

```
// create a variable to store textbox control
string mobile = "" 
// Text_mobile is a TextBox in aspx page
// A temporary variable to store variable in loop from table 
string var_mobile = "mobile"; // Currently I am hard coding
// now I wish to use this var_mobile to make automatically assign the value into main variable
<<var_mobile>> = TextBox_mobile.Text.Trim();
//and backend it should be actually storing same in earlier mobile variabl
mobile = TextBox_mobile.Text.Trim();
```

Since I have lot of objects and variables and later to work on variables, I want this to do in a loop like logic at a time instead of assigning them at individual basis.

Is there any such possible in Asp.net C#?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a Windows Forms control by name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @ElmoDev001 Its only for control objects. I do not have issue on that. I want to access variables remotely and assign values from appropriate control objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c# this and all things which require code to interact with data about types and their members declared within assemblies can be achieved using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection).

To get field using string containing its name you can use method [`GetField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfield?view=netframework-4.8) and then call [`SetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvalue?view=netframework-4.8) on [`FieldInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo?view=netframework-4.8) returned by [`GetField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfield?view=netframework-4.8).

For example, if you have class named `MyClass` declared like this

```
class MyClass
{
    public int myField = 0;
}
```

You could use following code to set value of `myField`

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
string fieldName = "myField";
int valueToSet = 10;

typeof(MyClass).GetField(fieldName).SetValue(myClass, valueToSet);
```

Comment: This worked superb. You exactly found what I needed. Really appreciate it. I would place my code for more details, so that it can help many others.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that ;) If that's it then you can accept my answer as the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

As per Kacper prompt quick answer, I was able to resolve with his point to point resolution.

CommonClass.cs

```
public class CommonClass
{
     public string mobile = "";
     public CommonClass()
     {
         //
         // TODO: Add constructor logic here
         //
      }
}
```

My code in .cs file:-

```
    string mobile = "";

    CommonClass obj_class = new CommonClass();
    string fieldname = "mobile";
    typeof(CommonClass).GetField(fieldname).SetValue(obj_class, TextBox_mobile.Text);

    mobile = obj_class.mobile.Trim();
```