# How to set property(s) of a custom control using an onclick event in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a custom control (with the Class name as CG) with some properties:

```
    public int type = 0;
    public string control_name { get; set; }
    public int decimal_pt { get; set; }
```

Then there is a context menu assigned to it like below while creating the control dynamically:

```
void addDevProc(int type)
        {
            if (type == 0)
            {
                CG Cont = new CG();

                //Right Click settings
                MenuItem miprop = cm.MenuItems.Add("Properties");

                Cont.ContextMenu = cm;
                miprop.Click += devSet;
                
                fcon.Controls.Add(Cont);
            }
        }
```

And then I am calling a dialogbox for changing the above variables, as following:

```
private void devSet(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Control_Settings cs = new Control_Settings(fcon, fcon.GetType());
            var drDispSettings = cs.ShowDialog();

            if(drDispSettings == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ControlProps tempProps = new ControlProps();
                tempProps = cs._set;
                // Transfer Properties to device
                switch (tempProps.UnitType)
                {
                    case 0:
                        CG control = new CG();
                        control.id = tempProps.UnitAddress;
                        control.decimal_pt = tempProps.UnitDecimal;
                        break;
                        ...
                }
            }
        }
```

Here the _set is a property of type ControlProps.

Now I want to set the properties of fcon(focussed control) according to _set.

for that I've tried:

```
(fcon as CG).id = tempProps.UnitAddress; // It gives error "Object Reference not set..."
(CG)fcon.id = tempProps.UnitAddress;// Doesn't work "Control dosen't contain defination of id"
```

It would be great if you could point me out in correct direction. Thanks for your help!

Edit 1:

`fcon`(Type of fcon is Control) is the Control on which the right click was done.

`CG` is a class which stands for 'Control Graphics'.

`ControlProps` is again a class with some properties and methods which are generalised for the different types of custom control that I've made, `CG` is just one of them. I have done this as there are some shared properties between them.

Comment: What is `fcon` and where and how is it set? What is `CG`? How is `DeviceProps` and `ControlProps` related? It also would be nice if you take some time to strip your question from any unnecessary detail (like the event subscriptions).

Comment: @KlausGütter Please refer to the edit done after your kind suggestion. Also I missed renaming `DeviceProps` to `ControlProps` at that specific location for simplification purpose. Please let me know if you would need any other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `fcon` is not a `CG` the "as" call will return `null`.

What you want to do is something like

```
if (fcon is CG cg)
{
    cg.id = ...
}
```

This block of code will only run if `fcon` is a `CG`.

Also you would need to Iterate through parent of fcon and find the control that you are looking for, you can find the relevant info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp), and then use it in the above code.

Credits, Reddit user [u/lmaydev](https://www.reddit.com/user/lmaydev/) for the answer