# How can I call a chart method , that is including the code for n similar charts without programming the chart n times repeatedly?

Tags: c#, charts, switch-statement

I have n similar charts in my C# form app (chart1,chart2,chart3...chartn). These charts are located in the tabs of a tab control. All charts are managed over one method (Draw_Chart). I am calling the method with the related "chart" parameter like code below.
The method side is OK, but for calling the chart I am currently using a "switch" control. For each "step_no" (process step) in my program I have to call the related chart.
As I have a lot of steps and therefore a lot of charts the switch control has lot of cases that takes too much place in my code page. How can I shorten this part of my code?

Is it possible to shorten the cases with a loop or should I use another mechanism?

My greatest challanges for using a loop are:

1-Programming the "chart" parameter dynamically as chart1,chart2...

2-Programming the tabPage again dynamically as tabPage1,tabPage2,...

```
public method call_chart()
    {
     //This part I would like to program with loop in anyway... 
     switch (step_no)
        {
            case "1":
                Draw_Chart(chart1);
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
                break;

            case "2":
                Draw_Chart(chart2);
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
                break;

            case "3":
                Draw_Chart(chart3);
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage3;
                break;

            // several more case parts
        }
    }          


 public void Draw_Chart(Chart chart)
    {
        chart.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = ".";
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Current (% or A)";
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.TitleForeColor = Color.Cyan;
        // rest part of chart definition.
    }
```

Update-1

I have tried to shorten my code as below. BUt get following compile Errors:

for first row: error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart'

for second row: error CS1061: 'Control[]' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedTab' and no accessible extension method 'SelectedTab' accepting a first argument of type 'Control[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
for(int n=1; n<=step_no_max; n++)
        {
            if (step_no == n)
            {
                Draw_Chart(this.Controls.Find("chart"+n.ToString(),true));
                this.Controls.Find("tabControl"+n.ToString(),true).SelectedTab= tabPage1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a Windows Forms control by name in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Hello @GSerg ! I have tried your suggestion, but get errors. Have written in Update-1 under my question

Comment: You have glanced over the single line of code, [`Controls.Find()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536756/11683), and dumped it inside the expression without understanding what it is and [how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536739/get-a-windows-forms-control-by-name-in-c-sharp/1536756#comment13044825_1536756), or even whether it is the more fitting of the [solutions presented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1639106/11683)?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get you. I have looked to all the solutions in your link. But I cannot overcome the Errors. I think they are not suitable for my case. Could you please explaine if you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this suits your needs, but you could derive the target `chart` and `tabPage` using a [`switch expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression), and then use them for drawing the chart and updating the selected tab:

```
(Chart chart, TabPage tabPage) = step_no switch
{
    "1" => (chart1, tabPage1),
    "2" => (chart2, tabPage2),
    "3" => (chart3, tabPage3),
    _ => (defaultChart, defaultTabPage),
};

Draw_Chart(chart);
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage;
```

Here, I am assuming that you have fallback values for the chart and the tab page, if `step_no` does not match any of the values it is compared to (`defaultChart`, `defaultTabPage`). Depending on your use case, you may rather want to return `null` or some other objects for the default case (`_`).